# Water simulation that people use for product advertising

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation

I was working with 3D beverage before and I want to learn to make this flowing water and splash like this.

[image]

well, is it possible to make flowing water with good result like this using blender water simulation? and what is the software that beverage animation advertise that designer always use to create like this one?

than,this is my current design for now:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if you expect a simple "sure, do this" answer to such a complex fluid simulation... that simple answer would be, use guides in the Mantaflow simulation to simulate the fluid along curves. But if you have no idea how that works, you'll need full tutorials on this topic whch we cannot provide in a short answer here. Here are some tutorials on this topic: [Liquid Follows Curve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFr3y2S8nTw), [Create Water Bending in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EWVZUbPjiE&t=159s), [Mantaflow Guides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldUwslQJ9NQ)

Comment: surely i was found another water simulation that maybe what i need, its Realflow (thanks for the keyword). but disappointedly, it just for 3ds max, maya, and cinema 4d. yup, for now i will use mantaflow for rendering purpose for now. it solved